# Spring Boot validation, expect field when deserializing requestBody, but not from responseBody

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, jackson, lombok

I was wondering about a Spring Boot best practice.

I have a Spring Boot API which basically exposes another API.
It's a necessary evil. 
The external API is a complete disaster and we cannot directly expose this to our customers.

The problem is that this API sometimes expects fields in the requestBody, 
but doesn't return them to the consumer.

Translating that to Spring Boot (Javax validation or Lombok).
I cannot just put @Notnull or @Nonnull annotations on those fields.
Because it will fail when Jackson tries to deserialize the responseBody.

What should I do here?

- Should I make a seperate ObjectIn and ObjectOut
- Should I remove the annotation and do a custom conditional check in the restController
- Should I do something else entirely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request and response payloads are different, it probably makes sense to have different classes for representing them. And to deal with the boilerplate code of mapping DTOs to domain models (and the other way around), you may look into mapping frameworks, such as [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/), which integrates very well with Spring.

Alternatively to defining different classes for input and output, you may look into *validation groups*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Data is transfered in a JSON-Structure.

Use @JsonProperty(value = "example_field_name", required = false), with required set to false, to annotate your property. Then Jackson will throw no error if field is missing in the JSON-Structure.

[JsonProperty Documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html)

Comment: It should throw an error when the field is missing in the requestBody though? Just not in the requestResponse.

Comment: The Question is where is your Exception thrown? As your question says, I was assuming that you have a Problem with deserializing the Data Structure if fields are not present. So do you serialize the Structure on your own, or do you let spring do that for you? With @RequestBody for example? Anyway, the deserializing should not throw any if you defined the property as not required. Which is ok so. If your assuming a special constellation of properties to be set than i would recommend using validation for that.